# loading code from pastebin.com to tryfsharp.org

Tags: f#, pastebin

A page has a pastebin snippet embedded. I need a way to open tryfsharp.org with this snippet loaded in just by clicking a link at the page. It is possible if snippet is hosted at fssnip.net by using url in the following format "http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create?codeUrl={sourceurl}". When I insert pastebin url as parameter there, then completely wrong character set is loaded, including non-alphabetical characters. 
For example, here http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hprEq4A8 is code "let a = 1", when I open this url http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create?codeUrl=http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hprEq4A8 , it should display code "let a = 1", instead it displays something completely wrong. Anyone managed to make this work?

Comment: Asking help regarding a specific tool.

Comment: I agree with Ramon, this is a bug report for tryfsharp.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [F# Snippets](http://fssnip.net) instead of Pastebin :-). If you post an F# snippet there, it will add colorization and tooltips (just like those you see in F# in Visual Studio) and you can load the snippet to Try F# too.

For example, [this sample snippet](http://fssnip.net/iF) has a "tryfsharp.org" link that takes you to [Try F# and loads the snippet](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create?codeUrl=http://fssnip.net/raw/iF) using the URL: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create?codeUrl=http://fssnip.net/raw/iF

If you wanted to use Pastebin, then Pastebin needs to have `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file in the root (which tells Silverlight that accessing that domain is allowed). You can have a look at [the file on fssnip.net](http://fssnip.net/clientaccesspolicy.xml) So, this is not a feature request for Try F#, but for Pastebin.

Comment: I know about fssnip.net, I was saying about it in the question actually. The reason I prefer pastebin is once a snippet is embedded somewhere and I update it at pastebin, the embedded snippet will be updated automatically. While embedded snippet from fssnip is a copy paste of markup, it will not keed in sync with updates at fssnip.

Comment: @Alexey That is a useful feedback. I'll see if we can add some nice embedding support to fssnip in the future :-)

Comment: @Alexey But I guess the technical details about `clientaccesspolicy.xml` might still be useful - if you can get someone from Pastebin to copy the file there...

Comment: Yes, definetly useful. I get that it is not possible with pastebin now. I doubt they will add the file, but I might try to suggest it to them if I will need this feature even more than currently. Thank you.